# Python: Create list with Multi-choice value. Error: An open collection property was found. In OData, open collection properties are not supported

Tags: python, python-3.x, odata, office365api

I am adding item to SharePoint list using below code:

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.runtime.client_request import ClientRequest
from office365.runtime.utilities.request_options import RequestOptions
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext

app_settings = {
        'url': 'url',
        'client_id': 'clientid',
        'client_secret': 'secret'
    }

context_auth = AuthenticationContext(url=app_settings['url'])
context_auth.acquire_token_for_app(client_id=app_settings['client_id'], client_secret=app_settings['client_secret'])
ctx = ClientContext(app_settings['url'], context_auth)
print("Create list item example...")
list_object = ctx.web.lists.get_by_title("listtitle")
item_properties = {'__metadata': {'type': 'SP.List'}, 'Title': 'Task Created by Python Script',
                           'CategoryDescription': 'This is a test Task created by Python script with the help of Office 365 library.'}
```

I could successfully add item to the list with above code.

Now when I try the same to pass with Multi-choice values like below, it does not work

```
item_properties = {'__metadata': {'type': 'SP.List'}, 'Title': '01 Task Created by Python Script', 'CategoryDescription': 'This is a test Task created by Python script with the help of Office 365 library.'
                   'ChoiceField':{
                         '__metadata' : {'type' : 'Collection(Edm.String)' },
                         'results': ['value 1', 'value 2']
                     }
                  }
```

On running with the above, receiving below error:

`An open collection property 'ChoiceField' was found. In OData, open collection properties are not supported.", "400 Client Error: Bad Request for url:..."`

No luck in finding the solution. Can someone help me resolve the issue?

**Update: I even raised the issue on Github page of Python office-365 libraray. Issue can be found [here](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/issues/134)**

Answer (score -1):

I'm not expert in working with python and sharepoint API, 
but it seems you're trying to add an item to the list and also adding choices at the same time.
I believe that this list should be existing with choices field, that when adding you just add which choice you're selecting for the added item.

I hope it can help.

Comment: No, when I create new item without passing value for choice field, it works fine. But, when I create another new item with multi-choice then I get an error. Requirement is to create new list item on SharePoint online through Python script

Comment: So this question is about a multi-choice, where a field expected to have multiple selection (I thought it was only a simple one choice combobox).
I hope now that it will clarify the question.

Comment: I've updated the question. Anyway, I was passing multiple values in my payload